# Canvas Rotation collision detection on a sprite

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, physics, javascript, html-canvas

I am using this code to detect collisions between two rectangular sprites.

```
intersect: function(other) {
    return this.x < other.x + other.width && other.x < this.x + this.width &&
        this.y < other.y + other.height && other.y < this.y + this.height;
},
```

My question is how can I account for rotation of the sprite.  This will only work with the

initial rotational position of the sprite.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Each rectangle has 4 corners and 4 sides. If either corner are within the boundaries of the 4 sides of the other rectangle, or if a diagonal of one rectangle cross a diagonal of the other, they collide.

First, calculate the positions of all the corners, if you know your geometry this shouldn't be too hard.

From here on, vector maths will make it all a lot simpler, go read on the topic if needed. For this purpose we need only points, vectors and the concept of dot products, you can leave the more advanced stuff for later.

Specifically the property that the dot product of two vectors is positive if the angle between them is acute, and negative if it is obtuse is needed.

Look at my beautiful drawing, the angle between vector `a` and `b` is acute, this tells us that the point `b` is pointing to is on the inner side of `c`. `a` and `d` has the opposite property, so `d` is pointing to a point outside the rectangle. Perform such a check for each of the 4 sides.

[image: Freehand rectangle FTW!]

For the crossing diagonal part, you can check if two line pieces intersect by constructing a quadrilateral first taking an endpoint from the first line, then one from the second line, then the other endpoint from the first line, and finally the other endpoint of the second line. If the figure is convex, the lines pieces intersect. To find if a polygon is convex, you can take the determinant of each side as a vector and the following side, if either all of the results are positive, or all negative the polygon is convex.

One of my previous answers might prove useful: [Vector problem: which one is the left / centre / right one?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15920/vector-problem-which-one-is-the-left-centre-right-one/15922#15922)

Comment: Does this work if one sprite is large enough and contains the other sprite completely? There's no edge intersection in this case.

Comment: @davidluzgouveia Yes, this method does not use edge intersection, it checks if there are corner points of one rectangle within the other, which would still be the case if one rectangle enclose the other completely. And then there is the diagonals crossing check which sorts out a few special cases where the rectangles do overlap but all 8 corners stick out.

Comment: I see. I'll need to try this approach next time as it sounds much easier for rectangles than implementing the separating axis theorem, which is what I have done before in this situation. As an added note, would this work for any convex polygon too?

Comment: Actually I might have made it a bit rectangle specific, rather than the dot product of `b` and `a` you should use the determinant of `b` and `c` to check how `b` is positioned relative to `c`. The crossing diagonal check obviously needs to be replaced for non 4 sided polygons, you need each corner to be connected to a diagonal which is checked, and you need the entire set of diagonals to be directly or indirectly connected through crossing one another.

Comment: OK I just read through your answer and I am still fully absorbing this info.  I was hoping there was a way to do this that wasnt too complicated but, looking around no choice but to hunker down and figure out the math required.

Comment: Give me a day or two to try and implement this before I mark this as the top answer.  While this is a really good answer any supplementary info would be helpful.

Comment: I cant get my head wrapped around this... I try to calculate my corners using trigonometry but that doesnt come out right for some reason.  And are there any articles or books that can clarify what you mean?

Comment: Wikipedia always provide some answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics) do remember that you have to choose an centre, if you are not working in a coordinate system where the point you wish to rotate about is not (0,0) you must first subtract the centre point, then rotate, and then add the centre point to the result.

Comment: Thanks for the response so where should I add it back in at   for example if I am calculating it like this should I add it back in at the points before sin and cosin or after the total calculation.     Not quite clear on this.  I have tried many different things.  this.bottomRightX = (newCenterX * Math.cos(radian)) - (newCenterY * Math.sin(radian));

Comment: Total, to rotate `(X,Y)` around `(centerX,centerY)` it's simply this: `rotatedX = (X-centerX)*cos(angle) - (Y-centerY)*sin(angle) + centerX`

Comment: Thanks eBusiness, it works as long as I dont move as soon as I move it throws it all off.  I update the  (X,Y) to the last rotatedX and it does not return the proper rotatedX hmmm...I know I have to update the rotatedX to the new position after I move it. Maybe I need to rethink how I am approaching this

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162943(v=vs.85).aspx  also according to this you should be able to get x1 with just x' = (x * cos A2) - (y * sin A2)  so why do i need to subtract x from the rotation point??

Comment: That article is only about rotation around the origin, when you want to rotate around a different point you have to take that into account. Post what code you have made, there is probably an error in it.

Comment: Ok thank I really appreciate your help on this.  I got this working pretty good now.  It still goes off every time I cross the mid point of the canvas stage for some weird reason but I can deal with   that for now.  I think that has to do with an error somewhere in the framework I am using.

Comment: Now I will be moving on to implementing the next stage of your solution.  As before give me a few days to grasp this concept and implement it... which of course wont work and Ill be back lol.  Ill be back ;)

Comment: Now that I am attempting to implement this method I am noticing that this is very similar to the SAT method.  I am thinking I might just try to implementing the SAT method.   What do you suggest?

Comment: Both are valid choices, it depends a bit on how you plan to react to a collision, SAT might be simpler in some regards, but it doesn't directly give you a point of collision. I think they are performance wise pretty similar, given that you start out with a quick elimination check like bounding spheres.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Checking to see if a corner is included is an interesting approach, and will catch all collisions if the sprites are moving slowly enough, but it will miss some fast-moving thin sprites. Consider this case:

```
    o---o
    |   |b
    |   |
o---+---+-o
|   |   | |a
o---+---+-o
    o---o
```

Here, the tall rectangle `b` and the wide rectangle `a` clearly intersect, but neither contains any vertices other than its own.

**Solution**

The people behind the games N and N+ (Metanet Software) have a brilliant tutorial [here](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) -- the long and the short of it is to use the separate axis theorem; for each face on both shapes, compute the [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_normal) for that face and project both shapes onto that line

```
aaaaaa          Normal 1:  a
a    a                     a 
a    a  bbbbbb             ab  ] overlap by 2
aaaaaa  b    b             ab
        bbbbbb              b

Normal 2:
aaaaaa
        bbbbbb
      ^
      no overlap
```

If the two shapes overlap, then **all** of their projections will overlap. If the two shapes do not overlap, then at least one of their projections will not overlap.

**You're halfway there already**

You might note that testing for overlap in the projection is very similar to what you're already doing for non-rotated rectangles. That's because for aligned rectangles, there are only two normals to project onto -- the X and Y axes.

In any case, the Metanet folks did a great job, and have interactive demos, so definitely check that out. [Here's the link again](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html). Or if it's down, use the [wayback](http://web.archive.org/web/20110722153051/http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) or [google](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) cached copies.

Comment: Thanks for the additional idea I am looking at SAT type collision detection.  My problem lies in that I dont understand how to project the lines into the imaginary surface if you will.  I am trying to though.  Trying really hard